# Moving info from CSV file to databse

Tags: python, sqlite

Sorry about all the code below, however, I want ti give as much context for the question as possible. I am trying to create take a csv file and put certain headers into a database, which is then kept in a dictionary or a list. I have gotten to the point where my code will take only the headers needed but when I add the values into the database and returned, all I got when printed is ({}, {}, [], {}).

```
import const 
import sqlite3 
import csv

SEP = ','

def get_pokemon_stats():
    """Reads the data contained in a pokemon data file and parses it into
    several data structures.

    Args:
        None

    Returns: a tuple of:
        -a dict where:
            -each key is a pokemon name (str)
            -each value is a tuple of the following stats:
                -pokemon name (str)
                -species_id (int)
                -height (float)
                -weight (float)
                -type_1 (str)
                -type_2 (str)
                -url_image (str)
                -generation_id (int)
                -evolves_from_species_id (str)
        -a dict where:
            -each key is a pokemon species_id (int)
            -each value is the corresponding pokemon name (str)
        -a list of all pokemon names (strs)
        -a dict where:
            -each key is a pokemon type (str). Note that type_1 and type_2
            entries are all considered types. There should be no special
            treatment for the type NA; it is considered a type as well.
            -each value is a list of all pokemon names (strs) that fall into
            the corresponding type
    """
    name_to_stats = {}
    id_to_name = {}
    names = []
    pokemon_by_type = {}
    DATA_FILENAME = 'pokemon.csv' 
    con = sqlite3.connect('poki.db')
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS poki')
    cur.execute( ' CREATE TABLE  poki( pokemon TEXT, species_id INTEGER,'
             ' height REAL, weight REAL)' )

    values = ('INSERT INTO poki VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)')

    with open('pokemon.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader =csv.reader(csv_file)
        for line in csv_reader:
            list_of_values = (line[1] ,line [2], line [3], line[4])

            cur.execute(values, list_of_values)
            return cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: well, you never *do* anything with those `dict`s and that `list`, you just return them, so what were you expecting?

Comment: You're not actually reading from the database, only executing the `INSERT INTO` command

Comment: Also, every time you run this script, it'll drop and recreate the entire table... Seems inefficient

Comment: How would I read from the database, I thought if I used fetch all I can see what was inside it.

Comment: You need to run `SELECT * FROM poki`, then `fetchall` will return stuff

Comment: Generally, you would separate out the function that adds data from the one that actually reads it back out

Comment: Right, so using the select from poki worked but it tells me that I only have the first header from the list, rather than the whole list in each table. Do you know how I can solve this? As for the drop table we were instructed that every time the program ran to create a new table.

Comment: Read about [sqlite3.Connection.commit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit)